# Return an element from a function (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I want to return an element from the function but I get the error "lateinit property policlinic has not been initialized". By the way, when I try to write to the Toast message, data comes in successfully.

```
private var equelControl: String? = null

private fun useranddoctor(): String? {
    val collection = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    collection.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            for (document in documentSnapshot) {
                if (document.getString("kullaniciseviyesi") == "1" && document.getString("email") == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email) {
                    equelControl = document.getString("policlinic")!!
                } else if (document.getString("kullaniciseviyesi") == "0" && document.getString(
                        "email"
                    ) == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email
                ) {
                    equelControl = firebaseAuth.uid
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {

        }
    return equelControl
}
```

where I use useranddoctor. The code whereEquelsTo will change according to doctor or user.

```
fun realtimeList(
        collectionPath: String,
        context: Context,
        cevapdurum: Boolean,
        field: String
    ): LiveData<MutableList<Any>> {
        //  Toast.makeText(context, useranddoctor().toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Any>>()
        val docRef = Firebase.firestore.collection(collectionPath)
        docRef
            .whereEqualTo(field, useranddoctor())  ------> this error "Suspend function 'userAndDoctor' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"
            .whereEqualTo("cevapdurum", cevapdurum)
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                firebaseFirestoreException?.let {
                    Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    //  Log.i("hata",it.message.toString())
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                            )
                    }                 
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why you want policlinic as lateinit? You can directly make it as nullable.

Comment: can you write the corrected code

Comment: Please check the answer. Also if helpful upvote it.

Comment: @ÖmerSeyfettinYavuzyiğit are you using coroutines in this project? This code is asynchronous so you cannot return the value this way. If you're using coroutines, you can make this a `suspend` function that can return the value (because it's async behind the scenes but is used in a direct style). If not using coroutines, then you have to use callbacks to do the stuff you need with the result - you can't rely on the value being present when you return here.

Comment: The error you get now is because you're trying to call a `suspend` function from a regular one. This is general coroutine usage and is a bit outside the scope of this question. That's why I mentioned in my answer that if you're not already familiar with coroutines, you will need to learn a bit about them from the docs. In this specific case, you should likely create your live data with `liveData { ... }` and emit stuff to it from inside the block (which can call suspend functions) - check [this doc for more info](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how asynchronous calls work, you cannot return the value from this function because it is set in a listener that will be called in the future (after your function has returned). You need to use the `policlinic` value from inside this callback. For instance, you could pass a callback to your function instead of returning a value.

That said, direct style with function calls and return values is usually more convenient. If you need to do asynchronous operations in a sequential manner, I suggest you use Kotlin coroutines.

There are helpers that allow you to await for the listener to be called and get the value like you want to. For instance, using [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services), you can use the `await()` extension function on your `Task<QuerySnapshot>` to get a `QuerySnapshot` directly:

```kotlin
private suspend fun userAndDoctor(): String? {
    val documentSnapshot = Firebase.firestore.collection("users").get().await()
    for (document in documentSnapshot) {
        if (document.getString("kullaniciseviyesi") == "1" && document.getString("email") == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email) {
            return document.getString("policlinic")!!
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Note that the function above is marked `suspend`. This means that, while it looks like a regular function with a return value, it executes asynchronously behind the scenes. In order to call it, you'll need to start a coroutine.

If you're not familiar with coroutines, I suggest you [learn about them first](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) before going this path (it will be very useful anyway if you work on Android).

---

**EDIT**: The error you get now is because you're trying to call a `suspend` function from a regular one. This is general coroutine usage and is a bit outside the scope of this question. That's why I mentioned in my answer that if you're not already familiar with coroutines, you will need to learn a bit about them from the docs. In this specific case, you should likely create your live data with `liveData { ... }` and emit stuff to it from inside the block (which can call suspend functions) - check [this doc for more info](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata).