# mutableListOf() I want to use it globally using lateinit Kotli

Tags: kotlin

```
private lateinit var participants: mutableListOf<ParticipantDTO>



participants = mutableListOf<ParticipantDTO>()



private fun searchMatchInfoByMatchID(matchId: String,summonerName: String){
    lolAPIForMatch.getMatchInfoByMatchID(matchId, API_KEY)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<MatchDTO>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MatchDTO>, response: Response<MatchDTO>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful.not()){
                    return
                }

                response.body()?.let {

                   
                    it.info.participants.filter {
                        it.summonerName == "${summonerName}"
                    }.forEach {
                        
                        participants.add(it)
                    }
                    participantAdapter.participants = participants
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MatchDTO>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
}


participantAdapter.participants = participants
```

First, declare it as a global variable.

After initialization in `onCreate` function.

By putting data into participants in the `searchMatchInfoByMatchID` function

I want to assign participants to `participantAdapter.participants`, but the data is not being allocated.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752178/return-an-element-from-a-function-kotlin, it's a very similar problematic

Comment: Why must the value of participants be global? The issue you are running into is you never know when "onResponse" is called, so when you are setting the adapter to the updated list, you can't guarantee the data is there. When you try to set the list to the adapter after iterating, it looks as it should work. I would suggest adding a function on the adapter to accept the unfiltered list from body, and then inside that function do the rest of the work to filter, and to set the list inside the adapter